# How to allow select2 text to overflow select?

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

My select text is cut off with ellipses, for instance: `This is my selec...`

But I want my text to spill out to `Infinity`, without affecting the position of anything on the page.

I want the text to spill out on top of anything that gets in its way.

How?

Comment: Try increasing width for the div containing the text.

Comment: I posted the solution I found

Comment: What is the current code for your select text element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
.select2-container .select2-selection--single {
  width: 999999999vw !important;
}
```